Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0 for Azure.AI.FormRecognizer
The project framework is .NET 4.8. I installed Azure.AI.FormRecognizer 4.1.0, which requires minimum Azure.Core 1.34.0 which requires System.Diagnostic.DiagnosticSource 6.0.1. But for some reason the FormRecognizer asks for 6.0.0.0. Am I missing something obvious?
This is the output:
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.dll but was not handled in user code
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In the app.config it gets generated as
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.1" newVersion="6.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>

And I tried to change it to 6.0.1.0 but that didn't do anything.
This is what the error looks like during runtime:
     private Uri _uri;
     private AzureKeyCredential _credential;
     private DocumentAnalysisClient _analysisClient;
     private DocumentModelAdministrationClient _modelClient;

     public AzureOcr()
     {
         _uri = new Uri(_diEndpoint);
         _credential = new AzureKeyCredential(_diKey);
         _analysisClient = new DocumentAnalysisClient(_uri, _credential); // here it throws "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'"
         _modelClient = new DocumentModelAdministrationClient(_uri, _credential);
     }


Are you getting this error locally?

Yeah, when I run the application and the DocumentAnalysisClient from the FormRecognizer gets instantiated I get the error. I'll post the error I get during runtime too.

Are you using console app?

Please share the error in text format.And also share the code.

WPF  and one of the class libraries uses Azure

Please let me know which template you are using?Image

I'm using a Class Library (.NET Framework) C# which is 4.8

I am able to run the app with the above package versions.I am not getting any error.

That is very odd...

If possible please share your code repo.

Check this Image

Azure core 1.34, azure ai formrecognizer 4.1.0, diagnosticsource 6.0.1, class library .NET framework 4.8? I guess it's just an issue in the project I'm working in, well sht. Also unfortunately can't share, because it's of work :/

Yes same versions

Well that's sad, I'll keep looking, will keep this post updated.

If possible, share your code repo will check what is the issue in your app.

What does your app.config look like, it also says 6.0.0.1 for diagnosticsource, right? Can't share because it's from work unfortunately.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In the main class library there was an older version of DiagnosticSource 5.0.0.0, I changed that to 6.0.0.1 and it was resolved. Unfortunately very project specific.
